# Unable to google Google-API directory

Tags: google-api, gdata, gdata-api, google-api-java-client

I know its silly, but previously this URL used to show me all available google open source API's [Pervious working API link](http://code.google.com/intl/en/) but now its showing some other page. I am tired of searching the complete API directory. I want to pick one to learn. I have managed to find a similar page which shows only partial API's directory. [Google API directory](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory) Can any one provide me the correct URL to see complete directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit, it's a mess if you take a fresh start.

Accessing Google Apis can be basically be done in two ways.

1. **The old way** : Google Data Java Client Library (a.k.a. "gdata-java-client") : [docs here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/). Implemented services can be found at [Google Api Docs](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory) (the link you are referring to).
2. **The new way** : Google API Client Library for Java (a.k.a. "google-api-java-client") : [docs here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/). The [Api explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/) shows the generated client libraries using the new infrastructure. Or this [list](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs).

Both libraries are available for different languages and for different Google services. GData is the most mature library and supports [most services](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory).

The new way however is more flexible : the client libraries and even the docs can be **automatically generated for any Google service** that is ready to transition to the new infrastructure. On the downside, [not all Google services](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs) have a client library ready for the new infrastructure (e.g. Contacts).
You can access services that are not yet transitioned but you have to write [your own XML model](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.4.1-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/xml/atom/package-summary.html).

There is a [migration guide](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/MigratingToGoogleApiJavaClient) to move from GData to new infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

try to find it on this page:
http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?company=Google

or you can explore some apis here: (i don't know if thats all)
http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/

or just search what you need on:
http://developers.google.com